# AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data to save

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to insert a dataframe's values inside an SQL table on Databricks.

The thing is, there is no (apparent) duplicate columns in the dataframe. I checked. What this could be?

```
 |-- nr_cpf_cnpj: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tp_pess: string (nullable = true)
 |-- am_bacen: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_moda: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_sub_moda: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vl_bacen: decimal(29,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- clivenc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vl_envio: decimal(28,2) (nullable = true)
 |-- nm_pess_empr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nr_cnae_prin: long (nullable = true)


spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE db.tb_jul_bcn  SELECT * FROM tmpBcnView")
```

The dataframe is in the tmpBcnViewas a temp view

Error:

```
AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data to save: nr_cnae_prin
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2987275027841731> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 spark.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE db.tb_jul_bcn  SELECT * FROM tmpBcnView")
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46             start = time.perf_counter()
     47             try:
---> 48                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49                 logger.log_success(
     50                     module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1117             sqlQuery = formatter.format(sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1118         try:
-> 1119             return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self)
   1120         finally:
   1121             if len(kwargs) > 0:
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976272/pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception-column-ambiguous-but-no-duplicate-column-na   Print out the physical plan and see if there are duplicate columns in the physical plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved!

It happens that instead of having duplicate columns, there was an excedent column. The error was claiming a duplicate so I was searching the duplicate. That's just it!

Comment: Thanks Paloma! Your answer saved me a lot of trouble during an overnight failure at work ;) Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You saved me a ton of time with your answer. Horrible error logging from Databricks when you're right, it's actually just a column that the Target table doesn't currently have in it's schema.

In my case, I'm automatically adding data to a new table - My fix for anyone curious was just to use the "mergeSchema" option, as Delta lake allows for schema evolution.

```
new_records.write.format("delta") \
.mode("append") \
.option("mergeSchema", "true") \
.saveAsTable(f"{catalog_name}.{target_database_name}.{target_table_name}")
```

In my case, new_records is the dataframe I'm trying to add to my delta table.

Thanks again OP!